# How to update both model and view value in Angular directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ngmodel

Apologies in advance, directives are not my strong suit!

I have a simple attribute-only directive, the purpose of which is to automatically convert a string in a field to an HH:mm format upon `blur`'ing the field. This is the directive:

```
(function () {

    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.format-as-time')
        .directive('formatAsTime', timeDirective);

    timeDirective.$inject = [
        'isValid'
    ];

    function timeDirective (isValid) {

        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            restrict: 'A',
            link: LinkFunction
        };

        function LinkFunction (scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {

            elem.bind('blur', function () {

                var currentVal = ngModel.$modelValue,
                    formattedVal = '';

                // Format something like 0115 to 01:15
                if (currentVal.length === 4) {
                    formattedVal = currentVal.substr(0, 2) + ':' + currentVal.substr(2, 2);

                // Format something like 115 to 01:15
                } else if (currentVal.length === 3) {
                    formattedVal = '0' + currentVal.substr(0, 1) + ':' + currentVal.substr(1, 2);

                // Format something like 15 to 00:15
                } else if (currentVal.length === 2) {
                    formattedVal = '00:' + currentVal;
                }

                // If our formatted time is valid, apply it!
                if (isValid.time(formattedVal)) {
                    scope.$applyAsync(function () {
                        ngModel.$viewValue = formattedVal;
                        ngModel.$render();
                    });
                }

            });
        }

    }

}());
```

And the associated view:

```
<div ng-controller="TestController as test">
    <input type="text"
           maxlength="5"
           placeholder="HH:mm"
           ng-model="test.startTime"
           format-as-time>
    <button ng-click="test.getStartTime()">Get Start Time</button>
</div>
```

And the associated Controller:

```
(function () {

    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.testModule')
        .controller('TestController', TestController);

    function TestController () {

        var vm = this;

        vm.startTime = '';

        vm.getStartTime = function () {
            console.log(vm.startTime);
        }

    }

}());
```

At present, the directive works as expected for the view but the model in my controller does not get updated, i.e. the input will contain 01:15 but the model will `console.log()` 115.

I have tried using:

```
scope: {
    ngModel: '='
}
```

in the directive but this did not do anything.

Have I done this the right way, and if so what do I need to add to ensure both the model and view remain in sync?

If I have done this the wrong way, what would be the best way to do it correctly?

Comment: What does the isValid service look like?

Comment: `isValid` is just a factory that exposes a few functions to check if values are valid. `isValid.time()` is just a simple regex for an HH:mm string. Interestingly this is where the problem lies.

`isValid.time()` returns true at the point the view is rendered in my directive above. But when then trying to test the controller model `isValid.time()` returns false, and shows that the model contains the pre-formatted value.

Comment: Instead of `ngModel.$viewValue = formattedVal;`, try `ngModel.$setViewValue(formattedVal);` which should run the value through the normal model pipeline which sets the ngModel.

Comment: I have tried this before and it didn't work, but I have just tried it again now and it worked fine! I hate to admit it, but I think I may have used `ngModel.$setViewValue = formattedVal;` when I tried this in the past so no wonder it didn't work. Would you mind putting this as an answer and I'll accept it? :)

Comment: Added an answer.  I'm glad it worked but I'm like you directives aren't my strong suit and often set my head spinning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in this line `ngModel.$viewValue = formattedVal;`  Angular has a pipeline used to set a modelValue which includes running it through registered $parsers and $validators.  The proper way to set the value is by calling [`$setViewValue(formattedVal)`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) which will run the value through this pipeline.

Comment: Thank you! I had already tried this and it didn't work, but my syntax was incorrect: `ngModel.$setViewValue = formattedVal;`